# Verb and object inversion following a comma in a list?

Tags: sentence-structure, word-order, grammar-identification

I was looking to translate the following sentence, which describes a state, then lists several actions that are carried out:

> Exhausted from her perilous flight, she sheds her wings, …

I got to:

> Ermüdet durch ihren gefahrvollen Flug, sie wirft ihre Flügel ab, …

Then my grammar senses started tingling. I’ve googled to the moon and back, and checked in a couple of grammar books but can’t be sure what to look for: should the *sie wirft* be *wirft sie*?

My gut says yes, but I’m still not sure. What grammar rule does this fall under?  I've come to believe this is because of the verb-in-second position rule, and that, because it is closed by a comma, “Ermüdet durch ihren gefahrvollen Flug” effectively takes up the first position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to write *wirft sie.*

If you deconstruct the sentence, you will realise that *durch ihren gefahrvollen Flug* is superfluous and we could shorten it to:

> Ermüdet wirft sie ihre Flügel ab, …

And then we realise that *ermüdet* is nothing more than a participle which functions as an adverb here and can be moved around like anything else:

> Sie wirft ermüdet ihre Flügel ab, …
>
> Sie wirft ihre Flügel ermüdet ab, …

Since the extended participle *ermüdet …* occupies the first position, the finite verb must be in second.

By the way, it is not necessary to add a comma between *Flug* and *wirft.* The comma would only be mandatory if the participle construction is inserted or appended to the main clause as per § 77 (7) of the official German orthographic rules. Thus:

> Sie wirft**,** ermüdet durch ihren gefahrvollen Flug**,** ihre Flügel ab, …
>
> Sie wirft ihre Flügel ab**,** ermüdet durch ihren gefahrvollen Flug, …

The comma is optional for preceding participles as per § 78 (3):

> Ermüdet durch ihren gefahrvollen Flug(,) wirft sie ihre Flügel ab, …

Leaving out the comma makes it clearer that we are dealing with a single sentence and the verb is required to be put before *sie.* But beware: Even if we extend the participle into a subordinate clause (which has an obligatory comma after it), the main clause’s verb must come next:

> Weil sie durch ihren gefahrvollen Flug ermüdet ist, **wirft sie** ihre Flügel ab, …

Answer (score 3):

It should be *wirft sie*: This puts the verb in second position as it should be, if you regard the phrase *Ermüdet durch ihren gefahrvollen Flug* as one part of speech.

Comment: Thanks Martin, when Stephie commented on my post to say that I was right, this was the justification I began to take on board. Glad to have it confirmed.

Comment: @Matt Great, I saw your comment one second after I posted my answer.